# At what $t$ does there exist a real $k$ such that $\vec{u}=\vec{v}$? What is $k$ at those various times? Does a complex $k$ always exist for all $t$?

Tags: trigonometry

$$\vec{u}=\langle2R\cos\left(4t+\phi\right)+R\cos\left(2t+\phi\right),2R\sin\left(4t+\phi\right)-R\sin\left(2t+\phi\right)\rangle$$
$$\vec{v}=\langle2Rk\cos\left(4t\right)+Rk\cos\left(2t\right)+\frac{R}{2}\sin\left(4t\right)+\frac{R}{2}\sin\left(2t\right),$$
$$2Rk\sin\left(4t\right)-Rk\sin\left(2t\right)+\frac{R}{2}\cos\left(2t\right)-\frac{R}{2}\cos\left(4t\right)\rangle$$

You can of course set $R=1$ without loss of generality

[Here is a desmos simulation](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/qvqhhk8xso) to illustrate the problem.

1. For what $\phi$ does there exist $t$ for which there exists a real $k$ such that $\vec{u}=\vec{v}$?
2. For a given choice of $\phi$, what are the values of the various $t$ for which there exists a real $k$ such that $\vec{u}=\vec{v}$?
3. In each of those cases, what is the value of $k$?
4. Does a complex $k$ always exist for all $t$ and all $\phi$?

I think an approach I could take is to first solve an easier version of the problem by translating it into one about determining when two lines rotating about the origin will overlap. These lines rotating about the origin are the respective spans at time $t$ of $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$ as they rotate about the origin. Solving this easier problem will help to narrow down the possibilities for our desired values of $\phi$. For a visualization of the rotating lines problem see for instance [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/pbdabjrepv) how for $\phi=2$ we get two rotating lines that never overlap.

---

#### Case 1: $\phi=2n\pi$, $n$ $\in$ $ℤ$

We can answer question 2 easily in this case. We can test out all values of $t$ between zero and $\pi$ and identify that our desired $t$ values are:

$$t_1=0$$

$$t_2=\pi/3$$

$$t_3=2\pi/3$$

You can also easily see that at each of these times the value of $k$ is $1$

---

#### Case 2: $\phi=(2n+1)\pi$, $n$ $\in$ $ℤ$

We can answer question 2 easily in this case. We can test out all values of $t$ between zero and $\pi$ and identify that our desired $t$ values are:

$$t_1=0$$

$$t_2=\pi/3$$

$$t_3=2\pi/3$$

You can also easily see that at each of these times the value of $k$ is $-1$

---

To answer question 1 we can begin by first solving the overlapping lines problem. Consider the different lines spanned by vectors $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$ at any given time as they rotate about the origin. From there, we can concern ourselves with finding the set of all possible $\phi$ for which there exists a time $t$ at which the slopes of the two lines are equal. Note that this only will help us determine when we can find a real $k$ such that $\vec{u}=c\vec{v}$ for some real scalar $c$. Thus, while this will not fully answer the question it can help to narrow things down a bit first.

Since we want to know if there exists a real $k$ such that there's a real $t$ at which the respective slopes of the two lines are equal, then what we want is really just the set of all $\phi$ for which there exists some $k$ such that there are real zeros of

$$\frac{2\sin\left(4x+\phi\right)-\sin\left(2x+\phi\right)}{2\cos\left(4x+\phi\right)+\cos\left(2x+\phi\right)}-\frac{2k\sin\left(4x\right)-k\sin\left(2x\right)+\frac{1}{2}\cos\left(2x\right)-\frac{1}{2}\cos\left(4x\right)}{2k\cos\left(4x\right)+k\cos\left(2x\right)+\frac{1}{2}\sin\left(4x\right)+\frac{1}{2}\sin\left(2x\right)}$$

Let's call this very long expression $M$

I think that a conclusion that can be made is the following: there exists $t$ for which there exists a real $k$ such that $\vec{u}=c\vec{v}$ ($c$ $\in$ $ℝ$) if and only if $M$ has a nonzero number of real zeros.

Given that $M$ is periodic, for any given $\phi$ it either has zero real zeros or infinitely many real zeros.

It does seem that in order to get $\vec{u}=\vec{v}$ as opposed to $\vec{u}=c\vec{v}$ the value of $\phi$ must be $2n\pi$ or $(2n+1)\pi$

I could be wrong about this, though

---

Just for the sake of it, an alternative route to answering question 1 is to use a dot product.

Let $$\vec{w}=\langle-\left(2R\sin\left(4t+\phi\right)-R\sin\left(2t+\phi\right)\right),2R\cos\left(4t+\phi\right)+R\cos\left(2t+\phi\right)\rangle$$

I've deliberately chosen this vector $\vec{w}$ because it is perpendicular to $\vec{u}$. We want to solve for all $\phi$ for which the equation $\vec{v} \cdot \vec{w}=0$ has real solutions in $t$

Just as before, this approach would only help narrow down the possibilities for the desired values of $\phi$

---

Consider the following variation of the above problem:

1. For what $\phi$ does there exist $t$ for which there exists a real $k$ such that $\vec{u}=±\vec{v}$?
2. For a given choice of $\phi$, what are the values of the various $t$ for which there exists a real $k$ such that $\vec{u}=±\vec{v}$?
3. In each of those cases, what is the value of $k$?
4. Does a complex $k$ always exist for all $t$ and all $\phi$?

This variation of the problem seems the most difficult to me. I'll come back to this variation eventually and attempt to make progress on it.

---

Consider yet another variation of the problem:

1. For what $\phi$ does there exist $t$ for which there exists a real $k$ such that $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$ are collinear?
2. For a given choice of $\phi$, what must be the relationship between $k$ and $t$ in order for $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$ to be collinear?
3. Does a complex $k$ always exist for all $t$ and all $\phi$?

The answer to the first question is simply the collection of all $\phi$ for which there can be some real $k$ such that there are real zeros in $x$ of

$$\frac{2\sin\left(4x+\phi\right)-\sin\left(2x+\phi\right)}{2\cos\left(4x+\phi\right)+\cos\left(2x+\phi\right)}-\frac{2k\sin\left(4x\right)-k\sin\left(2x\right)+\frac{1}{2}\cos\left(2x\right)-\frac{1}{2}\cos\left(4x\right)}{2k\cos\left(4x\right)+k\cos\left(2x\right)+\frac{1}{2}\sin\left(4x\right)+\frac{1}{2}\sin\left(2x\right)}$$

Assuming an appropriate value of $\phi$, the answer to the second question is that $t,k$ is any pair of reals which solve

$$\frac{2\sin\left(4t+\phi\right)-\sin\left(2t+\phi\right)}{2\cos\left(4t+\phi\right)+\cos\left(2t+\phi\right)}-\frac{2k\sin\left(4t\right)-k\sin\left(2t\right)+\frac{1}{2}\cos\left(2t\right)-\frac{1}{2}\cos\left(4t\right)}{2k\cos\left(4t\right)+k\cos\left(2t\right)+\frac{1}{2}\sin\left(4t\right)+\frac{1}{2}\sin\left(2t\right)}=0$$

Comment: Are the capitalized $T$s significant in any way?

Comment: @user170231 they were an accident due to copy and paste. I fixed it

Answer (score 2):

Not a full answer but enough work to be worth showing

As you noted, $R$ does nothing and has no effect on the problem (I think mentioning $R$ in question $3$ is a red herring). You are trying to solve the equations

$$2\cos\left(4t+\phi\right)+\cos\left(2t+\phi\right)=2k\cos\left(4t\right)+k\cos\left(2t\right)+\frac{1}{2}\sin\left(4t\right)+\frac{1}{2}\sin\left(2t\right)$$

$$2\sin\left(4t+\phi\right)-\sin\left(2t+\phi\right)=2k\sin\left(4t\right)-k\sin\left(2t\right)+\frac{1}{2}\cos\left(2t\right)-\frac{1}{2}\cos\left(4t\right)$$

Rearranging

$$k=\frac{2\cos\left(4t+\phi\right)+\cos\left(2t+\phi\right)-\frac{1}{2}\sin\left(4t\right)-\frac{1}{2}\sin\left(2t\right)}{2\cos\left(4t\right)+\cos\left(2t\right)}$$

$$k=\frac{2\sin\left(4t+\phi\right)-\sin\left(2t+\phi\right)-\frac{1}{2}\cos\left(2t\right)+\frac{1}{2}\cos\left(4t\right)}{2\sin\left(4t\right)-\sin\left(2t\right)}$$

To get a valid $k$, these must be equal

$$\frac{2\cos\left(4t+\phi\right)+\cos\left(2t+\phi\right)-\frac{1}{2}\sin\left(4t\right)-\frac{1}{2}\sin\left(2t\right)}{2\cos\left(4t\right)+\cos\left(2t\right)}=\frac{2\sin\left(4t+\phi\right)-\sin\left(2t+\phi\right)-\frac{1}{2}\cos\left(2t\right)+\frac{1}{2}\cos\left(4t\right)}{2\sin\left(4t\right)-\sin\left(2t\right)}$$

At this point, the algebra is tedious but doable. Assuming I haven't made any mistakes, it simplifies to

$$0=1 - \cos(6t) + 4 \sin(2t - \phi) + 6 \sin(\phi) + 4 \sin(6t + \phi)$$

There is indeed a [band](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=1%20-%20cos%286t%29%20%2B%204%20sin%282t%20-%20p%29%20%2B%206%20sin%28p%29%20%2B%204%20sin%286t%20%2B%20p%29%3E0) where this equation has no solutions, which seems to be centered on $\phi=\frac{\pi}{2}+2\pi n$ (for integer $n$). Solving for the width of this band will tell you when solutions exist.

Comment: I think I did get rid of the red herring in one of my edits. Thanks for sharing your progress.  Solving for the width of the band seems easier said than done but I do of course think you are right about that